# How can I chain .html() and .fadeIn() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
$('.container-modal-cash').html().fadeIn(1500);
```

It throws:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).html(...).fadeIn is not a function

Why? And how can I fix it?

Generally I'm setting a content (using `.html`) inside an element and then showing it (using `.fadeIn`). What's wrong?

Comment: the `html` method returns a string (*getting* the HTML content) when you don't provide an argument to it. It only provides the chained jQuery element when you provide an argument to `html` (which only *then* sets the HTML content).

Comment: which `jQuery` version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The `.html()` can be used to set the contents of the element, or get the contents of the element. `FadeIn/Out` methods work on the Jquery selector element ( I mean `$('.test')` ).

Courtesy of [Trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459839/trincot), you can also use the `fadeIn/fadeOut()` methods, when you set the content of the element using `html()`.

```
$('.test').html("final content").fadeOut(1500).fadeIn(1500);
```

please refer the below example demonstrating this.

```js
console.log("getting the contents inside");
console.log($('.test').html());
console.log("setting the contents inside");
$('.test').html('changed content');

//fade works on the JQuery selector element.

$('.test').fadeOut(1500);
$('.test').fadeIn(1500);

// you can chain the fadeIn/fadeOut methods like so

$('.test').fadeOut(1500).fadeIn(1500);

// you can also chain the fadeIn/fadeOut when setting the html content like so.

$('.test').html("final content").fadeOut(1500).fadeIn(1500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">content</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This thing only works when you set some html inside `html` function.

```js
$('.container-modal-cash').html("testing fadeIn").fadeIn(1500);

//below will fail with same error - uncomment below code to verify
//$('.container-modal-cash').html().fadeIn(1500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-modal-cash"></div>
```